# How do I connect one event from one button to another button?

Tags: java, swing, events, button

I've got a script, which reads and uploads the image, which executes by pushing on one button. I've got another button, which supposed to take this image and read the metadata. However, I dont know, how to connect these events. So, this is the code for first event, by first button.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {         
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.showDialog(null, "Open image");
    File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
    String filename = file.getAbsolutePath();
    JTextField_path.setText(filename);

    ImageIcon icon= new ImageIcon(filename);
    jLabel_image.setIcon(icon);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First button code

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
..................................
//Set selected path in text field.
JTextField_path.setText(filename);
..................................
}
```

You have another button code like

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
..................................
//Now read the above selected image by getting path from text field
String path = JTextField_path.getText();
..................................
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I've got a script, which reads and uploads the image, which executes by pushing on one button. I've got another button, which supposed to take this image and read the metadata. However, I dont know, how to connect these events.

You can't "connect" the events, since that's not how event-driven programming works, but you can change an object's state and base behavior on that state. I would make the image a field of the class. One solution would be to have in the 2nd JButton's ActionListener an if test to see if the image field is null, and if not, to post an error JOptionPane, and if it's not null, to extract the information out of it. A second and better solution is to make the second JButton disabled, and in your first ActionListener, get the image data, set the image field with the image object, and then activate the 2nd JButton by calling `setEnabled(true)` on the button or its Action.

> So, this is the code for first event, by first button.

In the future, please post a [minimal example program](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), not these small snippets. This is not a full code dump, but rather a small compilable and runnable program that demonstrates your problem for us.

Comment: Okay, next time I'll post in this way and thanks for advice.